# xargs print output from wc -l

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I would like to use `xargs` to count the number of blocks of 4 lines in a list of compressed files, and do the counting in parallel using 8 CPUs, like this:

```
find $PWD/ -name "*.ext.gz" | xargs -t -n1 -P8 -I % gunzip -c % | paste - - - - | wc -l
```

Currently, this one-liner does the calculation but I cannot see the output count except for the last one.

What do I need to add to be able to see the number coming from `wc -l` associated to the input file?
Any ideas?

Comment: It works here. Are you sure it isn't just taking a long time?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves it's only printing out the result of the last file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you have a wrong assumption. It would appear that you expect that

```
gunzip -c <filename> | paste - - - - | wc -l
```

will be run for each file that `find` reports. This is incorrect. What is actually happening is that

```
gunzip -c <filename>
```

is being run for each file, the outputs of each uncompressed file are all being combined into one large body, and `paste - - - - | wc -l` is being run on that combined result.

A better approach would be to write a short shell script, say `count_groups.sh` that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nlines=$(gzcat $1 | wc -l)
(( ngroups = nlines / 4 ))
echo "$1 : $ngroups"
```

Then, run `chmod +x count_groups.sh`, and run

```
find $PWD/ -name "*.ext.gz" | xargs -t -n1 -P8 -I% ./count_groups.sh %
```